# Autoscaling of PODs in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Is there any API that we can use to upscale/downscale the number of PODs in AWS EKS ?

I tried to go through the documentations related to horizontal pod autoscaling but that doesn't fulfil my requirement as I want to create an API to scale the pods and that approach focuses more on kubectl commands.

Comment: Are you looking for `kubectl scale --replicas=<some number> deployment/<yourdeployment>`?

Comment: Yeah, basically I am looking for an API which implements above kubectl command or some sdk which I can use to execute the above command in java.

Comment: It's a convenience function in the CLI. You'll likely need to update the `replicas` value for the relevant object directly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using `client-java-api` offered by kubernetes.
`listNamespacedDeployments` method can be used to get the deployments and pods based on the deployments.

`replaceNamespacedDeployments` can be used to replace the specified deployment to upscale or downscale the number of pods.